# how to simplify includes though out multiple directories

Tags: php

I am using `php5.5`.

I have multiple directories throughout my domain as well:

`domain.com/games/gamename/index.php
domain.com/games/gamename/server/databaseconnect.php
domain.com/games/gamename/actionone/dosoemthing.php`

and many more pages in different directories. I need to include `databaseconnect.php` on almost every page (but not all). After the page is done doing it's function I have a

```
header("Location dir/file.php");
```

I am trying to find a good way to simplify the directories to use something similar to

```
<base href="domain.com/">
```

I've tried using

```
$root = dirname(__DIR__);
```

and

```
$root = dirname(__FILE__);
```

but when I use these it throws a large hyperlink that isn't functional

```
domain.com/public/cpanel_username/public_html/games/gamename/ with a 404 error.
```

Any ideas how to simplify both of these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$root = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
```

Comment: the echo on this shows the same as dirname(__ FILE __); when i tried it..<Br>`/home/cpanel_login/public_html/games/gamename` **ignore the space in file - it didn't keep the __ when I squished it together - this is for display only**

Comment: you know what - disregard my above comment -- It's pulling the server side location and echoing that, but the functionality translates to the `public's` hyperlink - thanks!

Comment: Glad you figured it out! :)